# neural network time series prediction tsDyn nnetTS

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I'm using tsDyn package to predict time series data in R. there is a function in this package called nnetTs. However when I try to predict, it just gives me 1 output and does not provide x steps ahead forecast. See eblow for the code:

```
library("tsDyn")
set.seed(1234)
mod.nnet <- nnetTs(log(lynx), m=2, size=3,steps=12)
mod.nnet
predict(mod.nnet,steps=12)
```

here is the output (as noted above, I'm just getting 1 single output and not 12 steps ahead prediction). I'm not sure what the issue is, I read the documentation, I'm stuck.

```
Time Series:
Start = 1935 
End = 1935 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 7.80263
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run

```
predict(mod.nnet,n.ahead=12)
```

at the last line. The argument for selecting forecast horizon is `n.ahead` not steps.